# bigquery extract epoch from date

Tags: google-bigquery

I need to extract epoch from the timestamp column in bigquery.
In postgres we can get the epoch using following query:

```
extract(epoch from timestamp_column)
```

What is the equivalent in bigquery?
How to get epoch from a given date in bigquery?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are using Legacy SQL, you can use `TIMESTAMP_TO_SEC` to convert from [timestamp to epoch](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/legacy-sql#timestamp_to_msec=). 
So, you can do something like this:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP_TO_MSEC(timestamp_column) FROM [YOUR_DATASET:YOUR_TABLE];
```

If you are using Standard SQL, you can use `UNIX_SECONDS` [for the same purpose](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#unix_seconds).

```
SELECT UNIX_SECONDS(timestamp_column) FROM `yourdataset.yourtable`;
```